# cygnus and NGSI v2 suport?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Does cygnus supports NGSI v2 specifications? I tried to do subscriptions following the NGSI v2 format but it is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This question was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836534/fiware-context-broker-issue-with-ngsiv2-subscriptions) and [here](stackoverflow.com/questions/37114255/why-cygnus-crashes-when‌​-using-ngsiv2-in-ori‌​on)