# Subscription status change after post

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

After successfully installed Cygnus connector and testing the creation of subscriptions.

With bellow files:

**agent_1.conf**

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = hdfs-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = hdfs-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = [ PERSONALIZED SERVICE NAME ]
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /[ PERSONAL SERVICE PATH ]
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIHDFSSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_host = storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_port = 14000
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username = [ MY USERNAME ]
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token = [ MY TOKEN ]


cygnus-ngsi.channels.hdfs-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.hdfs-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.hdfs-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

**cygnus_interface_1.conf**

```
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf
AGENT_NAME=cygnus-ngsi
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log
ADMIN_PORT=8081
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

### TESTING WITH NGSI V1

I have tried creating a subscription as presented below:

[ POST ]

```
http://[ MY ORION IP ]:1026/v1/subscribeContext
```

[ HEADER ]

```
Content-Type:application/json
Accept: application/json
Fiware-Service: [ PERSONALIZED SERVICE NAME ]
Fiware-ServicePath: /[ PERSONALIZED PATH ]
```

[ BODY ]

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "PhysicalTest",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "TEMPORAL"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "test"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "test"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
```

### TESTING WITH NGSI V2

I also have tried creating a subscription as presented below:

[ POST ]

```
http://[ MY ORION IP ]:1026/v2/subscriptions
```

[ HEADER ]

```
Content-Type:application/json
Accept: application/json
Fiware-Service: [ PERSONALIZED SERVICE NAME ]
Fiware-ServicePath: /[ PERSONALIZED PATH ]
```

[ BODY ]

```
{
  "description": "Subscription to store physical tests",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "PhysicalTest",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "TEMPORAL"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "test"
      ],
      "expression": {
        "q": "test!=0"
      }
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://localhost:5050/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2018-04-05T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
```

When checking previously created subscription. I found it with: "status": "active"; which is great.

### THE POST

In both type of subscriptions (i.e., through v1 and v2) I post as showed below:

[ POST ]

```
http://[ MY ORION IP ]:1026/v2/entities
```

[ HEADER ]

```
Content-Type:application/json
Accept: application/json
Fiware-Service: [ PERSONALIZED SERVICE NAME ]
Fiware-ServicePath: /[ PERSONALIZED PATH ]
```

[ BODY ]

```
{
    "id": "TEMPORAL",
    "type": "PhysicalTest",
    "test": {
        "value": "Timed Up and Go",
        "type": "test-type"
        },
    "sensor": {
        "value": "Accelerometer",
        "type": "sensor-type",
        "metadata": {
            "speed": {
                "value": "80",
                "type": "hz"
                }
            }
        },
    "data": {
        "value": "0.0635477304458618,0.00490868091583252,0.0516815185546875,2016-09-08T10:51:41.341Z-0500",
        "type": "sensor-data"
        }
}
```

### THE FAIL RESULT

The status of my subscriptions in both cases **turn to: "status": "failed"**

Moreover, there is no evidence of that Cosmos is storing anything while looking at the directories where entity files should be stored:

```
curl -X GET "http://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/[ MY USERNAME ]?op=liststatus&user.name=[ MY USERNAME ]" -H "X-Auth-Token: [ MY TOKEN ]" | python -m json.tool
```

### JUST FOR THE RECORD

I have already successfully tested the Cygnus connection by:

```
./notification-json-simple.sh http://localhost:5050/notify
```

Thus, I presume they might be something with my subscription mechanism, but still cannot find the glitch.

### ORION LOG retrieved FROM /tmp/ContextBroker.log

```
.
.
.
time=Sunday 29 Jan 19:41:07 2017.697Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=1485717075-957-00000000006 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=AlarmManager.cpp[328]:notificationError | msg=Raising alarm NotificationError localhost:5050/notify: (curl_easy_perform failed: Couldn't connect to server)
```

Any hint to solve this?

Comment: Two guesses: first, do you try specifying the entity id in the subscription creation (not using "idPattern")? You can test something like this:  `"entities": [
{
"id": "ypioca",
"type": "room"
}
],`
Second, try to create the subscription with /v1 instead of /v2. I had this problem with STH Comet: seems to work with /v1 api.

Comment: I deleted previous comment because I was wrongly testing. My last try was by setting "idPattern": "false", and my subscription still active now :). But, still cannot retrieve any that is suppose to be storing on Cosmos, how do you do that?

Comment: Did you try registering subscriptions with `/v1/subscribeContext` instead of `/v2/subscriptions` as I told? And putting the entity id? Also, I think where you put "idPattern" is "isPattern".

Comment: I tried  with v1/subscribeContext same behaviour as before, "status": "active" but after posting it turns to "status": "failed"

Comment: I edited the post with both mechanism v1 and v2 I'm using for the subscription, without success

Comment: When "status" changes to "failed" it typically means that notification delivery had some problem. The ContextBroker log could provide information about it. Could you have a look to that file (typically at `/var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log in conventional installation), pls?

Comment: thanks for replying @fgalan I edited the question with today's orion log, which by the way I retrieve from docker; since I'm running Orion as a container.

Comment: would this error give any insight: time=Sunday 29 Jan 19:41:07 2017.697Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=1485717075-957-00000000006 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=AlarmManager.cpp[328]:notificationError | msg=Raising alarm NotificationError localhost:5050/notify: (curl_easy_perform failed: Couldn't connect to server)

Comment: Yes, that error is the key to discover the problem... However, I din't see it after the question post in the section "ORION LOG retrieved FROM /tmp/ContextBroker.log"... Maybe that section should be edited, so it includes just the above log error (this way it would be clear if some other user gets into this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently everything was about the notification reference. By changing localhost for respective IP address, my subscription keeps alive (i.e., keeping "status": "active") after any post. I have also tested notifying/triggering a notification from Orion to a third party server successfully as well as Cosmos.

Comment: It makes sense... note that when Orion runs inside docker, "localhost" means "Orion docker container itself". I guess that Cygnus was running externaly (either in a separate container in the same host or in a the host istelf) so you need to use the IP in that case, as you correctly explain in your self-answer.